# Reference Request Fixed Point with correction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose we have a mapping:
$$
T: \operatorname{CDF} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}: F \mapsto F
$$
which maps Cumulative Distribution Functions to functions on $[0,\infty)$. I am looking for a fixed point of this mapping. If I apply the normal fixed point iteration:
$$
F_{n+1} = TF_n,
$$
I have divergence and $F_n$ becomes some ridiculous function. However since I know we should have $F(\infty) = 1$ I scale $F_n$ by setting
$$
\tilde{F}_n(s) = F_0 + (1-F_0)(F_n(s) - F_n(0))/(1-F_n(0)),
$$
where $F_0$ is chosen such that $T\tilde{F}_n(\infty) = 1$. If we define:
$$
H: \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}
$$
by setting $HF=\tilde{F}$ where $\tilde{F}$ is chosen as $\tilde{F}_n$ above we are actually considering the composition:
$$
T\circ H: \operatorname{CDF} \rightarrow \operatorname{CDF}
$$

This method does indeed work and yields (for my example) the fixed point of $T$. Is there some general theory to this type of operation, as it seems to me that this is a technique which can be applied in a farely general framework.

Comment: Notice that a fixed point must belong to the range of the function $F$, that is, to $[F(0),1)$.  In order to have the compactness of the domain it is enough to consider $F$ restricted to $[F(0),1]$.  Now you can use the IVT to conclude that $F$ has a fixed point, see [Brouwer fixed point theorem: one-dimensional case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#One-dimensional_case).

Comment: Hello, I think there is a misunderstanding: It is the map $T: C([0,\infty),[0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,\infty),[0,1])$ which is supposed to have a fixed point.

Comment: Yes, I see.  It would be good if you could describe your mysterious method which does work.

Comment: Ok I will explain it further let me edit

Comment: So, you convert the functions on $[0,\infty)$ to functions on $[0,1]$, and apply some fixed point theorem to the resulting operator acting from some subset of $C([0,1])$ into itself.  Am I right?

Comment: The domain of the functions is always $[0,\infty)$ but the range changes and to make sure that the image of $T$ satisfies $TF(\infty)=1$ I change the input function $F$ by scaling it. As I think about it, I start to doubt that there is some general theory about this.